# Корректное применение потоков в Swing

Tags: java, многопоточность, swing

Здравствуйте. 
Пишу программу с использованием java swing. По ходу программы в ней создаются несколько окон, а именно :
Окно авторизации (стартовое; в процессе авторизации введенные пользователем данные отправляются на сервер и проверяются)

В случае успешной проверки создается главное окно приложения, в котором и происходит основная часть программы.

Так же могут создаться побочные фреймы (например, окно выбора файла)

Так вот,в каком случае (обобщенно) для фрейма нужно создавать новый поток?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вообще-то весь GUI в SWING (и практически во всех других решениях) работает в одном потоке. Для фрейма и прочих элементов интерфейса никакие потоки не создаются. Вы можете создавать потоки сколько Вам нужно, но при взаимодействии с элементами интерфейса необходимо выполнять определённые действия по передаче управления потоку GUI в нужное время. Есть хорошая толстая книжка про Swing. Где-то в чулане пылится, не скажу как точно называется. Там в том числе написано как работать с потоками.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В отдельные потоки надо выносить те операции, которые могут занять столько времени, сколько непозволительно "висеть" вашему GUI.

Например, необходимо заполнить таблицу на форме данными из БД, которые должен вернуть запрос. И в некоторых случаях этот запрос может получать данные больше, скажем, 10 секунд. Если выполнять этот запрос в swing'овом потоке (нити), то на время получения данных приложение зависнет, ничего не сказав при этом пользователю, что непозволительно для уважающих себя приложений.